# How to change the file from excel to csv when download data from web by python request module?

Tags: python, csv, request

I am using python to download files from webpage, and after I submit the request, I get the headers like below:

> > > r.headers

```
{'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=SABR_Download.xls', 
'Content-Encoding': 'UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Expires': '0', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 
'Server': 'Apache', 
'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 
'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Date': 'Wed, 22 Jun 2016 04:21:54 GMT', 
'Content-Type': 'application/excel; charset=UTF-8'}
```

and here is the response header from Chrome developer tool:

Response Headers
view source

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=SABR_Download.xls
Content-Encoding:UTF-8
Content-Type:application/excel; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 22 Jun 2016 04:19:53 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

The default format of the download file is in Excel. My question is how could I download the file in csv format, instead of excel format. thank you.

Comment: try' Content-Type':'text/csv'

Comment: @MohammadAmin, can we change the response header content? I thought that was the return of the server, we can only change the header content in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the site you're downloading from provides a specific URL for downloading in a CSV format, you will have to download the Excel spreadsheet and parse it to get what you think is a reasonable translation of the data.

There is a Python module called `xlrd` that can help you with this: https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd

Comment: the file downloaded is in "Excel 2004 xml spreadsheet" format, which seems to be difficult to handle by python. Currently, I have 100 files in this format with same variables, I want to combine them using python code, do you know how to deal with it by python?